# Laravel Change URL name detail

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

How do I make the post single URL like myweb.com/post-name instead myweb.com/post-id ? its works fine with posts id, but not with post name.

here my current route.

```
Route::get('/{id}', [App\http\Controllers\PostController::class, 'show']);
```

and here my controller.

```
public function show($id)
{
    $post = post::find($id);
    return view('detail', ['post' => $post]);
}
```

thank you.

Comment: change id to name in route and controller so you query records by name.

`Route::get('/{name}', [App\http\Controllers\PostController::class, 'show']);

public function show($name)
{
    $post = post::where('name', $name)->first();
    return view('detail', ['post' => $post]);
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you are using the `$id` as the identifier to resolve the post object:

```
myweb.com/25
```

Then:

```
public function show($id) // $id = 25
{
    $post = post::find($id); // find() search for the PK column, "id" by default

    return view('detail', ['post' => $post]);
}
```

If you want to resolve the `$post` by a different field, do this:

```
public function show($name)
{
    $post = post::where('name', $name)->first();

    return view('detail', ['post' => $post]);
}
```

This should work for a route like this:

```
myweb.com/a-cool-post-name
```

---

As a side note, you could resolve the model automatically makin use of [Route Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-model-binding).